# error when setting an onclick to a listview/json

Tags: java, android, json, rss

I'm getting a json exception when I try to run my code. 
The problem happens on the onclick listener. I'm trying to have the application go to the article of the rss feed on click

Here is the main activity

```
public class Blocku extends ListActivity {

private RssListAdapter adapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    List<JSONObject> jobs = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    try {
        jobs = BlockuReader.getLatestRssFeed();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Error loading RSS Feed Stream >> " + e.getMessage() + " //" + e.toString());
    }

    adapter = new RssListAdapter(this,jobs);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
       super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

       String link = null;
    try {
        String url = Article.getUrl().toString();

        link = adapter.getItem(position).getString(url).toString();
         Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
           i.setData(Uri.parse(link));
           startActivity(i);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "error";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

}
```

---

here is the adapter:

```
public class RssListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONObject> {

public RssListAdapter(Activity activity, List<JSONObject> imageAndTexts) {
    super(activity, 0, imageAndTexts);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Activity activity = (Activity) getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate the views from XML
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_text_layout, null);
    JSONObject jsonImageText = getItem(position);


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //The next section we update at runtime the text - as provided by the JSON from our REST call
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.job_text);

    try {
        Spanned text = (Spanned)jsonImageText.get("text");
        textView.setText(text);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        textView.setText("JSON Exception");
    }

    return rowView;

} 


}
```

---

and the article class

```
public class Article {

private long articleId;
private long feedId;
private String title;
private String description;
private String pubDate;
private static URL url;
private String encodedContent;

private static String link;
/**
 * @return the articleId
 */
public long getArticleId() {
    return articleId;
}
/**
 * @param articleId the articleId to set
 */
public void setArticleId(long articleId) {
    this.articleId = articleId;
}
/**
 * @return the feedId
 */
public long getFeedId() {
    return feedId;
}
/**
 * @param feedId the feedId to set
 */
public void setFeedId(long feedId) {
    this.feedId = feedId;
}
/**
 * @return the title
 */
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
/**
 * @param title the title to set
 */
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
/**
 * @return the url
 */
public static  URL getUrl() {
    return url;
}
/**
 * @param url the url to set
 */
public void setUrl(URL url) {
    Article.url = url;
}
/**
 * @param description the description to set
 */
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
/**
 * @return the description
 */
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
/**
 * @param pubDate the pubDate to set
 */
public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
    this.pubDate = pubDate;
}
/**
 * @return the pubDate
 */
public String getPubDate() {
    return pubDate;
}
/**
 * @param encodedContent the encodedContent to set
 */
public void setEncodedContent(String encodedContent) {
    this.encodedContent = encodedContent;
}
/**
 * @return the encodedContent
 */
public String getEncodedContent() {
    return encodedContent;
}


}
```

Comment: when I'm running the debugger the logcat doesn't display a history anymore so it just shows the current line. How can I view the entire history. Sorry I'm still learning. I'm running eclipse btw

Comment: For me, when viewing logcat through eclipse, after the log hits some size limit, it does what you're describing: shows only the last line.  If I press the button to clear the current log, then things return to normal.  Similarly, restarting eclipse or just switching to a different emulator (or real device) solves the problem.

Comment: ok it just say 07-11 22:02:12.377: WARN/System.err(4914): org.json.JSONException: No value for "then it lists the site I want"

Comment: Where is the error actually being thrown from? Do you have a call stack?

Comment: 07-11 22:30:31.738: WARN/System.err(11342): org.json.JSONException: No value for "the url I wanted"
07-11 22:30:31.748: WARN/System.err(11342):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
07-11 22:30:31.748: WARN/System.err(11342):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
07-11 22:30:31.748: WARN/System.err(11342):     at com.my7h1c.utes.Blocku.onListItemClick(Blocku.java:51)
07-11 22:30:31.748: WARN/System.err(11342):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:342)

Comment: 07-11 22:30:31.748: WARN/System.err(11342):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
07-11 22:30:31.748: WARN/System.err(11342):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3561)
07-11 22:30:31.748: WARN/System.err(11342):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1831)
07-11 22:30:31.748: WARN/System.err(11342):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

Comment: 07-11 22:30:31.748: WARN/System.err(11342):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-11 22:30:31.748: WARN/System.err(11342):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
07-11 22:30:31.748: WARN/System.err(11342):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
07-11 22:30:31.748: WARN/System.err(11342):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 22:30:31.758: WARN/System.err(11342):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

Comment: From exactly which line inside onListItemClick does the JSONException originate?  If that line has eight things going on, which one thing on that line is the culprit? (It may be easier to find if each line did just one thing.)

Comment: Have you mention the calling activity in the mainfist file in your project

Comment: thanks for your help after you mentioned moving things I figured it out I changed the inside of the onclick to this

Comment: String link = Article.getUrl().toString();
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     i.setData(Uri.parse(link));
     startActivity(i);

Comment: although now it wont get the right url but it works any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONException is usually thrown when there are issues with parsing. Check how you are parsing the JSON. this says that you are trying to get a value for a key named "then it lists the site i want"

Comment: I figured out how to get rid of the error by replacing what was inside the onclick with "
String link = Article.getUrl().toString(); Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); i.setData(Uri.parse(link)); startActivity(i); " but now my problem is how do I get the position right now it just grabs the last articles url

Comment: link = adapter.getItem(position).getString(url).toString();? You need to get the item at position from the lists adapter. Either override that method or make a getter for the list. The item position needs to be included somewhere along the code.

Comment: I'm now getting an error on the string you gave that url cannot be resolved to a variable. any ideas?

Comment: your code is kinda messy. i don't really know what you are doing. the proper way to handle HTTP calls and json responses is to actually parse the returned json object into an array or something and use that one afterwards, after the json is parsed into an array get rid of all the json objects. also you should try to read about using static variables and what they do. you seem to have that one wrong.you are statically accessing variables which is kinda wrong if you have an array of the class objects.

Comment: its simple: call HTTP request; parse the json response into an array, make an adapter using the array. set the adapter to a list. on click get the n-th item from the array asigned to the adapter and use its contents.